# boto3.exceptions.ResourceNotExistsError: The 'cloud9' resource does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, cloud9-ide

I have tried in both python 2X and 3X and also updated boto to latest version

[image]

I am getting below exception when I tried to list the cloud9 IDE using boto 3

[image]

> I tried the boto3.resource() and boto3.client()

Ref : [Boto3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloud9.html#Cloud9.Client.list_environments)

Attached my code below

```
def deleteCloud9IDE(resource,accessKey,secretKey,region):

client = boto3.client(resource,aws_access_key_id=accessKey,aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,region_name=region)

responseCloud9IDEDetails = client.list_environments()
print(responseCloud9IDEDetails)
```

Kindly help me out

Comment: Oddly working now